# OpsWorks how to stop app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

How could I terminate/stop node.js app on Amazon OpsWorks, can this be done via GUI. If I shut down the process via kill command opsworks restart it.

Answer (score 1):

In the GUI, click the "stop" button associated with the instance.

Re your kill command problem, do you have auto healing enabled on the layer?  Sounds like yes.